# Get attribute values by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to get all `data-js` attribute values from the content by **BeautifulSoup.**

**Input:**

```
<p data-js="1, 2, 3">some text..</p><p data-js="5">some 1 text</p><p data-js="4"> some 2 text. </p>
```

**Output:**

```
['1, 2, 3', '5', '4']
```

I've done it with lxml:

```
>>> content = """<p data-js="1, 2, 3">some text..</p><p data-js="5">some 1 text</p><p data-js="4"> some 2 text. </p>"""
>>> import lxml.html as PARSER
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(content)
>>> root.xpath("//*/@data-js")
['1, 2, 3', '5', '4']
```

I want the above result via BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 4):

The idea would to find all elements having `data-js` [attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) and collect them in a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<p data-js="1, 2, 3">some text..</p><p data-js="5">some 1 text</p><p data-js="4"> some 2 text. </p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print [elm['data-js'] for elm in soup.find_all(attrs={"data-js": True})]
```

Prints `['1, 2, 3', '5', '4']`.

Answer (score 3):

May a faster method with `map` without list comprehension.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
d = "..."
# create a soup instance
soup = BeautifulSoup(d)
# find all p-elements containing an data-js attribute
p = soup.find_all('p', attrs={"data-js": True})
# unpack data-js attribute from p-elements and map to new list
print map(lambda x: x['data-js'], p)
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Comment: Thank you. upvoted, data-js attribute will be any tag.

Comment: @VivekSable I know, `True` just guarantees that the key `data-js` is present in the `p` element. So you not run into a `KeyError: 'data-js'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use find_all() for this, but you have to put the attribute name in a dictionary, because it can't be used as a keyword argument by itself.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(content)
data = html.find_all(attrs={'data-js': True})
```

See [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) for more explanation.